# JavaScript: How to find out if the user browser is Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser-detection

I need some function returning a boolean value to check if the browser is [Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome).

How do I create such functionality?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want to do feature detection instead (instead of asking "is this Chrome?" ask "can this do that I need?")

Comment: Amen to that - detecting specific browsers is exactly how we got the problem of sites refusing to work with any other browser than IE and Netscape, even when other browsers are perfectly capable of rendering them properly. Capability detection is the safer, future-compatible, way forward.

Comment: who knows? he might want to have user download a chrome extension

Comment: No - my point is to use some three.js just to create fun 3d box backgrownd=)  which works fast only in chrome...=)

Comment: This question illustrates the problem of user agent detection. Only three years later, the Fun 3D Box Background will (try to) load in Chrome my low-end mobile phone but won't even try in Firefox in my high-end desktop computer.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, agreed. The use case given isn't great. I have a situation where we've developed a proof of concept app and know for a fact that it only lays out correctly in Chrome, yet we'll be sending the link out to a bunch of non-technical execs. So for those who click the link and open it in IE/Firefox/Opera, we show a note explaining that this is just a POC and we will make it support their browser in future. I think that's a valid use case.

Comment: I agree feature detection is the way to go. but there are legitimate areas where you would like to detect. e.g. I want to monkey patch xhr.sendAsBinary for chrome only. my initial solution checked if filereader.readasbinary is implemented. however, i am having issues where it patches for certain mobile browsers as well and therefore upload fails. I want this fix only for chrome.

Comment: Another example where feature detection will not work: I want to detect whether entering the name of a site and TAB TAB makes it possible to use the site-local search, so I can add a tip.  This is not possible to do using feature detection.

Comment: Want to know why it might be relevant to know if a browser is Chrome?
How about Chrome not being able to load RSS feeds? So that instead of linking to a RSS feed that will fail to load in Chrome, you could actually provided a warning or redirect the user?
No thanks to you Google Chrome...

Comment: To those preaching feature detection... yes it's generally understood that it's preferable, but there are many cases where it's not viable, so the question has merit. Eg, polyfilling incomplete/incorrect implementations of a feature such as IndexedDB in IE/Edge.

Comment: Like @PicMickael I am also looking at this for RSS feed alternative info to the user, since Chrome does not provide any native RSS ability.

Comment: There are odd situations where Google Chrome browser has a specific bug/inconsistency that does not exist in other browsers. I had this few times in past five years or so...

Comment: I'd like to re-surface this question - is there a reliable & simple answer to this yet?  There are many questions like this on SO and yet most of them work off the `userAgent` function which even w3schools acknowledges is inaccurate.  I've tested some of the answers to this question and similar ones, and none of them are even 50% reliable.  If I'm better off asking a new question please let me know.

Comment: @5Diraptor - if you look at Jonathan's answer as Rion's top answer recommends you do, you'll see the history of revision "UPDATE"s -- what this history tells you is that no, there is no reliable and simple answer to this and there probably never will be. If you absolutely must detect _which browser_ instead of using feature detection you are going to have maintenance to keep up with changes.

Answer (score 228, accepted):

**Update: Please see [Jonathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13348618/557445) for an updated way to handle this. The answer below may still work, but it could likely trigger some false positives in other browsers.**

```
var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
```

However, as mentioned User Agents can be spoofed so it is always best to use feature-detection (e.g. [Modernizer](http://modernizr.com/)) when handling these issues, as other answers mention.

Comment: what is the reasoning behind using .toLowerCase  -  why not just navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome')  I see a lot of people use it but im not sure the point?

Comment: adding .toLowerCase just makes sure the string gets forced to lowercase, so when the string in the condition is checked, it evaluates correctly when checking against the user agent

Comment: @Serg because they do not have Chrome. It is only a skin around iOS Safari.

Comment: Strange, sometimes i used to fix bugs only for that skinned with chrome version of ios safari.

Comment: Just a note - IE9 has "chromeframe" in user agent.

Comment: if the browser is Maxthon it will return true also so check first if the browser is not maxthon and then check is it chrome

Comment: Feature detection is great, except when developing extensions for sites that return completely different views for Chrome than any other browser. Something that feature detection is no help with.

Comment: do not use @JonathanMarzullo suggestion anymore, in 2015 every browser has a window.chrome set :-(

Comment: @artfulhacker  .. IE will output `undefined` for `windows.chrome`.. if you even bothered to look at my full answer below you would see i account for that based on the vendor name, try looking at the condition in my statement first before badgering someones answer :)

Comment: @artfulhacker Stack Overflow is not the community for badgering people. IE11 outputs `window.chrome` as `undefined` .. so i will add a check for IE Edge, Thank You.. At least have some common courtesy like everyone else and leave a helpful comment instead of being rude :)

Comment: @artfulhacker My comment above was written in 2012, when IE Edge did not exist. Please see my full answer below. Every time i am notified or find out that a modern browser has changed, I update my answer below! But thank you for letting me know about IE Edge.outputting true for window.chrome :)

Comment: @JonathanMarzullo you're welcome, I even up voted the answer :-) maybe time to remove the comment since it can't be updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92180/discussion-between-artfulhacker-and-jonathan-marzullo).

Comment: Returns `true` in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Since a lot of browser returns true at this, here's the code I used which excluded Edge, Maxthon, iOS safari ...etc

`var is_chrome = ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1) &&(navigator.vendor.toLowerCase().indexOf("google") > -1));`

Comment: Opera (at least version 42) returns `Google Inc` to `navigator.vendor`, so this method is not bulletproof, something like `/Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor) && !/OPR/.test(navigator.userAgent)` would probably work better

Comment: take care that first part of check will return false on ios chrome

Answer (score 371):

To check if browser is **Google Chrome**, try this:

```
// please note, 
// that IE11 now returns undefined again for window.chrome
// and new Opera 30 outputs true for window.chrome
// but needs to check if window.opr is not undefined
// and new IE Edge outputs to true now for window.chrome
// and if not iOS Chrome check
// so use the below updated condition
var isChromium = window.chrome;
var winNav = window.navigator;
var vendorName = winNav.vendor;
var isOpera = typeof window.opr !== "undefined";
var isIEedge = winNav.userAgent.indexOf("Edg") > -1;
var isIOSChrome = winNav.userAgent.match("CriOS");

if (isIOSChrome) {
   // is Google Chrome on IOS
} else if(
  isChromium !== null &&
  typeof isChromium !== "undefined" &&
  vendorName === "Google Inc." &&
  isOpera === false &&
  isIEedge === false
) {
   // is Google Chrome
} else { 
   // not Google Chrome 
}
```

Example of use: https://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/RwQXZxJ?editors=1111

The reason this works is because if you use the Google Chrome inspector and go to the console tab. Type 'window' and press enter. Then you be able to view the DOM properties for the 'window object'. When you collapse the object you can view all the properties, including the 'chrome' property.

You can't use strictly equals true anymore to check in IE for `window.chrome`. IE used to return `undefined`, now it returns `true`. **But guess what, IE11 now returns undefined again.** IE11 also returns a empty string `""` for `window.navigator.vendor`.

**UPDATE:**

Thank you to [Halcyon991](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2180105/halcyon991) for pointing out below, that the new Opera 18+ also outputs to true for `window.chrome`. Looks like **Opera 18** is based on **Chromium 31**. So I added a check to make sure the `window.navigator.vendor` is: `"Google Inc"` and not is `"Opera Software ASA"`. Also thanks to [Ring](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219843/ring) and [Adrien Be](https://stackoverflow.com/users/759452/adrien-be) for the heads up about Chrome 33 not returning true anymore... `window.chrome` now checks if not null. But play close attention to IE11, I added the check back for `undefined` since IE11 now outputs `undefined`, like it did when first released.. then after some update builds it outputted to `true` .. now recent update build is outputting `undefined` again. Microsoft can't make up it's mind!

**UPDATE** 7/24/2015 - addition for Opera check

Opera 30 was just released. It no longer outputs `window.opera`. And also `window.chrome` outputs to true in the new Opera 30. So you must check if **OPR** is in the *userAgent*. I updated my condition above to account for this new change in Opera 30, since it uses same render engine as Google Chrome.

**UPDATE** 10/13/2015 - addition for IE check

Added check for IE Edge due to it outputting `true` for `window.chrome` .. even though IE11 outputs `undefined` for `window.chrome`. Thanks to [artfulhacker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588445/artfulhacker) for letting us know about this!

**UPDATE** 2/5/2016 - addition for iOS Chrome check

Added check for iOS Chrome check `CriOS` due to it outputting `true` for Chrome on iOS. Thanks to [xinthose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4056146/xinthose) for letting us know about this!

**UPDATE** 4/18/2018 - change for Opera check

Edited check for Opera, checking `window.opr` is not `undefined` since now Chrome 66 has `OPR` in `window.navigator.vendor`. Thanks to [Frosty Z](https://stackoverflow.com/users/488666/frosty-z) and [Daniel Wallman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2087307/daniel-wallman) for reporting this!

Comment: This does not work for IE10. typeof window.chrome in IE10 returns {object}

Comment: it wouldn't work in ie10 because ie10 does not have window.chrome.. . so this would return false in ie10.

Comment: if NOT chrome it would also return undefined or false

Comment: window.chrome didn't returned {object} in my computer. I think it would be VERY weird if window.chrome exists in the window object. So far I believe this is the correct answer.

Comment: ^ Exists in an IE browser I meant.

Comment: Worth noting that Opera now responds _true_ to window.chrome! Check out conditionizr.com which has a bulletproof detect + fix.

Comment: @Halcyon991 Thank you for the heads up! Looks like Opera 18 is now based on Chromium. I added a condition, to also check if the browser is **Google** (Chrome) vs **Opera** (Chrome), Thanks again

Comment: var isGoogleChrome = window.chrome != null && window.navigator.vendor === "Google Inc.";

Comment: @Mr.Bacciagalupe: I had to use Ring's updated answer to make this work `if(isChromium === true)` does not work in Chrome version 33.

Comment: @Ring: did you test this solution across browser versions? I could only test on Chrome 33, IE11 & Firefox 27 (latest versions of each as of writting, end of March 2014)

Comment: @Ring and @Adrien Be .. Thanks.. IE11 will now return true for `window.chrome` ... IE11 also returns a empty string for `window.navigator.vendor`. So if you test for both `window.chrome` and `window.navigator.vendor` then you should be fine. :)

Comment: Running IE11, "window.chrome" returns undefined in the console

Comment: @vogomatix Thanks.. I added the check back for _undefined_ since IE11 now outputs _undefined_, like it did when first released.. then after some update builds it outputted to _true_.. now recent update build is outputting _undefined_ again.. ohh silly Microsoft :)

Comment: So we have some builds of IE11 that don't pretend to be chrome and others that do - wonderful! :-)

Comment: @vogomatix .. if you have automatic updates ON for IE and windows 7 or 8, than you should be fine. One of these days Microsoft will get their act together .. or not :)

Comment: for the newest version of Opera this check fails. Still getting browser is Chrome on it. :(

Comment: Thanks @Martin Asenov .. i just added an additional check to my condition above to check for new Opera 30 due to it using the same Google Chrome engine, and outputing true to window.chrome. The above now detects only Google Chrome :)

Comment: this fails for Chrome on iOS because it's safari in a chrome skin I guess;

Comment: Thanks @xinthose .. I just added a check for IOS Chrome.. much appreciated! :)

Comment: @DanielWallman What Android version are you using? I tested this on Android 6.1 and it alerts() showing it detects it is Google Chrome .. for Desktop Chrome and Mobile Chrome. See example: http://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/WpQELR

Comment: As a side-note, this detects "chromium" as well as Google Chrome, FWIW...

Comment: @rogerdpack Thank you for notifying me :). When i have time I will have to add a check for  `navigator.plugins[i].name == 'Chromium PDF Viewer'` to make sure it is Google Chrome but not 'chromium', based on this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278770/how-do-i-detect-chromium-specifically-vs-chrome

Comment: Maybe same problem as Daniel Wallman here: my Android Chrome user agent contains the "OPR" string! `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; ASUS_Z012D Build/OPR1.170623.026) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.109 Mobile Safari/537.36`, therefore `isChrome()` returns *false*.

Comment: Thank you @FrostyZ and @DanielWallman for letting us know. I fixed it so Opera checks for `window.opr` is not `undefined`.

Comment: hmm, I have Opera 50 (Chromium 71) on my Android 7 phone.  It returns `undefined` for `window.chrome` and `window.opr`. Any ideas why?

Comment: When i console out `window.chrome` or `window.opr` on desktop Opera 58 it outputs those objects, so they do exist but also right after those objects it also outputs `undefined`. Not sure why? You might want to submit a bug and ask the Opera developers why that is? https://bugs.opera.com/wizard/

Comment: Note for TypeScript, you will need to do `const isChromium = (window as any).chrome;` and similar for the Opera check.

Comment: It's false positive for Samsung Browser... Here is the UserAgent string:
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.1; SAMSUNG GT-I9500 Build/LRX22C) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/2.1 Chrome/34.0.1847.76 Mobile Safari/537.36

Comment: The latest Edge user agent value is actually `Edg` and not `Edge` (see also these docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/web-platform/user-agent-string). So maybe this line: `inNav.userAgent.indexOf("Edge")` should be changed to `inNav.userAgent.indexOf("Edg")`.

Comment: The codepen link doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @MasterDJon I updated and fixed the above Codepen link so it should work now, thanks for letting me know:  https://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/RwQXZxJ?editors=1111

Answer (score 22):

If you want to detect Chrome's rendering engine (so not specific features in Google Chrome or Chromium), a simple option is:

```
var isChrome = !!window.chrome;
```

**NOTE: this also returns `true` for many versions of Edge, Opera, etc that are based on Chrome (thanks @Carrm for pointing this out).** Avoiding that is an ongoing battle (see `window.opr` below) so you should ask yourself if you're trying to detect the rendering engine (used by almost all major modern browsers in 2020) or some other Chrome (or Chromium?) -specific feature.

And [you can probably skip `!!`](https://www.bennadel.com//blog/3858-the-double-bang-operator-and-a-misunderstanding-of-how-javascript-handles-truthy-falsy-values.htm)

Comment: Opera actually returns `true` to `window.chrome`. Check out conditionizr.com which has a bulletproof detect + fix.

Comment: Well, Opera is basically Chrome though

Comment: I just don't understand why two times !! , u can directly use , if(chrome){  }

Comment: @vishalsharma, the `!!` converts the value to be either `true` or `false`. `typeof(window.chrome)` gives `"object"`, whereas `typeof(!!window.chrome)` gives `"boolean"`. Your code sample also works too because the `if` statement does the conversion.

Comment: yes that was i m trying to tell , *if* will take care of conversion.. yes but u r also right , for assignment we have to use this way..

Comment: As of today, this fails with Chrome 31 (latest) on iOS 7, iPhone 4

Comment: @Chris it fails on iOS because Blink can't be used, WebKit is used here so it would need to fallback to the [user agent](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent). However, you probably wouldn't want to consider this Google Chrome from a support standpoint since it's WebKit, not Blink.

Comment: This also returns `true` for Edge.

Comment: This is returning true in IE for me.  IE keeps returning exact same as Chrome of all userAgent and Navigator vars.

Comment: @Sam are you talking about IE or Edge? Edge is based on Chrome, which returns true for this property.

Answer (score 20):

even shorter: `var is_chrome = /chrome/i.test( navigator.userAgent );`

Comment: Return `true` in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Return `true` on Opera

Comment: this is a very wrong approach...

Answer (score 17):

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify({
  isAndroid: /Android/.test(navigator.userAgent),
  isCordova: !!window.cordova,
  isEdge: /Edge/.test(navigator.userAgent),
  isFirefox: /Firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent),
  isChrome: /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor),
  isChromeIOS: /CriOS/.test(navigator.userAgent),
  isChromiumBased: !!window.chrome && !/Edge/.test(navigator.userAgent),
  isIE: /Trident/.test(navigator.userAgent),
  isIOS: /(iPhone|iPad|iPod)/.test(navigator.platform),
  isOpera: /OPR/.test(navigator.userAgent),
  isSafari: /Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !/Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent),
  isTouchScreen: ('ontouchstart' in window) || window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch,
  isWebComponentsSupported: 'registerElement' in document && 'import' in document.createElement('link') && 'content' in document.createElement('template')
}, null, '  '));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, navigator.vendor === "Google Inc." on Opera (at least v.49) so using your code Opera appears as Chrome.

Comment: Somewhere in the world a kitten dies for every regex we don't actually need.

Comment: No explanations, no indications on false positive/negatives, just a piece of code dumped here... This response should really be downvoted. It isn't even an answer to THE question asked.

Comment: Unfortunately, `navigator.vendor === "Google Inc."` on Edge as well (at least v.89) so using your code Edge also appears as Chrome and `isEdge` becomes false (user agent for Chromium based Edge browser is `Edg`).

Answer (score 14):

As of Chrome 89 (March 2021), all earlier answers are obsolete. Chrome now supports [User Agent Hints](https://web.dev/user-agent-client-hints/#javascript-api). So now this should be done using:

```
navigator.userAgentData?.brands?.some(b => b.brand === 'Google Chrome')
```

Or, if you're not using Babel:

```
navigator.userAgentData && navigator.userAgentData.brands && navigator.userAgentData.brands.some(b => b.brand === 'Google Chrome')
```

This returns true for Chrome 89 and above, false for the latest Opera and Edge, and undefined for browsers that don't support userAgentData.

Comment: This is nice as `navigator.userAgentData.brands` actually returns the browser *brand*. The issue with other answers is they return `true` for Chromium-based browsers, like Edge.

Answer (score 8):

<s>var is_chrome = /chrome/.test( navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() );~</s>

This is an old answer, written more than 12 years back; as of now(i.e., August 2022)

---

**Update(August 2022):**

Nowadays, browser detection using user agent (user agent sniffing) is *usually a bad idea*. [Feature detection](https://modernizr.com/docs/) should be the way to go.

Reference: [Browser detection using the user agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent)

However, if you still wish to do so, use a third party library like

```js
var parser = new UAParser();
var result = parser.getResult();

console.log(result.browser);// {name: "Chrome", version: "104.0.0.0", "major": "104"}
console.log(result.device); // {model: undefined, type: undefined, vendor: undefined}
console.log(result.os);     // {name: "Windows", version: "10"}
console.log(result.engine); // {name: "Blink", version: "104.0.0.0"}
console.log(result.cpu);    // {"architecture": "amd64"}
```

```html
<script 
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/UAParser.js/1.0.2/ua-parser.min.js">
</script>
```

The above snippet use the library [ua-parser-js](https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js)

1. CDN - https://cdnjs.com/libraries/UAParser.js
2. npm - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ua-parser-js

P.S: Please note that UA sniffing is bad practice and use feature detection wherever possible.

Comment: I liked this, remember you can also do var is_chrome = /chrome/i.test(navigator.userAgent); too

Comment: Returns `true` in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: @Cobby: With all due respect, Edge was not released at the time. Thanks for the info :)

Comment: Return `true` on Opera

Answer (score 3):

If you're feeling brave, you can experiment with browser sniffing and get a version:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent;
if(/chrome/i.test(ua)) {
    var uaArray = ua.split(' ')
    ,   version = uaArray[uaArray.length - 2].substr(7);
}
```

This detected version might be a Chrome version, or a Edge version, or something else. Browser plugins can easily change userAgent and platform and other things though, so this is not recommended.

Apologies to The Big Lebowski for using his answer within mine.

Comment: Version is `"537.36"` in Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1
```

It is working on v.71

Comment: `navigator.userAgent.includes("Chrome")`

Comment: Be advised this will return true on Edge Chromium as well as Google Chrome. For my use case this was a positive but the OP may be targeting Google Chrome only.

Comment: Return `true` on Opera

Answer (score 3):

There are some optional window properties that that can be used when doing browser detection. One of them is the optional `chrome` property (Chromium) and the other the optional `opr` property (Opera).

If a browser has the optional `chrome` property on the Window object, it means the browser is a Chromium browser. Previously this meant Chrome in most cases, but these days many browsers are built on Chromium (including Edge and Opera) so only checking the presence of the property will not help to detect Chrome browsers specifically.

Then there are often several user-agents for different browser versions (Edg or Edge) or operation systems (EdgiOS, ChriOS and FxiOS).

I use the following logic and tested against a lot of cases (common user agents):

```
const GOOGLE_VENDOR_NAME = 'Google Inc.';

function isOpera(){
  return Boolean(window.opr);
}

function isChromium() {
  return Boolean(window.chrome);
}

function getBrowserName() {
  const userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
  const vendor = window.navigator.vendor;
  switch (true) {
    case /Edge|Edg|EdgiOS/.test(userAgent):
      return 'Edge';
    case /OPR|Opera/.test(userAgent) && isOpera():
      return 'Opera';
    case /CriOS/.test(userAgent):
    case /Chrome/.test(userAgent) && vendor === GOOGLE_VENDOR_NAME && isChromium():
      return 'Chrome';
    case /Vivaldi/.test(userAgent):
      return 'Vivaldi';
    case /YaBrowser/.test(userAgent):
      return 'Yandex';
    case /Firefox|FxiOS/.test(userAgent):
      return 'Firefox';
    case /Safari/.test(userAgent):
      return 'Safari';
    case /MSIE|Trident/.test(userAgent):
      return 'Internet Explorer';
    default:
      return 'Unknown';
  }
}

function isChrome() {
  const name = getBrowserName();
  return name === 'Chrome';
}
```

You can find this simplified code in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/edkw9fcr/):

The trick is to test against other browsers then Chrome (Edge, Opera) first. In all these cases in the switch the different possible identifiers for a browser are combined in one regular expression and tested against the user agent string. For Chrome and Opera additional tests for the window property are added and for Chrome we also check whether the vendor name matches the expected value.

---

**Note:** *I tested against a lot of different user agents, but won't claim here that this solution is flawless. Any suggestions for improvements, or failing browser detections are welcome so I can further improve this code.*

---

### UPDATE:

Fixed bug with Chrome on iOS (user agent CriOS) detection. Chrome on iOS doesn't have the `chrome: true` property on the window object, so should only be tested for presence of the user agent string.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me on Chrome on Mac. Seems to be or simpler or more reliable (in case userAgent string tested) than all above.

```
        var isChrome = false;
        if (window.chrome && !window.opr){
            isChrome = true;
        }
        console.log(isChrome);
```

Comment: `const isChrome = window.chrome && !window.opr;`

Comment: I guess, that answer downvoted by oneliners lovers. Despite, I understand your passion, I don't think you should downvote a perfectly correct answer based just on it.

Answer (score 1):

**To check if browser is Google Chrome:**

```
var isChrome = navigator.userAgent.includes("Chrome") && navigator.vendor.includes("Google Inc");

console.log(navigator.vendor);
// "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36 "

console.log(navigator.userAgent); 
// "Google Inc."
```

Comment: This shows `true` on Opera

Answer (score 0):

User could change user agent . Try testing for `webkit` prefixed property in `style` object of `body` element

```
if ("webkitAppearance" in document.body.style) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: In firefox: ("webkitAnimation" in document.body.style)  === true

Comment: FYI: 'webkitAppearance' no longer works either. Edge is now using it. Probably best to delete your answer. ^^

Answer (score 0):

To know the names of different desktop browsers (Firefox, IE, Opera, Edge, Chrome). Except Safari.

```
function getBrowserName() {
  var browserName = '';
  var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
  (typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined') && (browserName = 'Firefox');
  ( /* @cc_on!@*/ false || !!document.documentMode) && (browserName = 'IE');
  (!!window.chrome && userAgent.match(/OPR/)) && (browserName = 'Opera');
  (!!window.chrome && userAgent.match(/Edge/)) && (browserName = 'Edge');
  (!!window.chrome && !userAgent.match(/(OPR|Edge)/)) && (browserName = 'Chrome');

  /**
   * Expected returns
   * Firefox, Opera, Edge, Chrome
   */
  return browserName;
}
```

Works in the following browser versions:

```
Opera - 58.0.3135.79
Firefox - 65.0.2 (64-bit)
IE - 11.413.15063 (JS Fiddle no longer supports IE just paste in Console)
Edge - 44.17763.1.0
Chrome - 72.0.3626.121 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

View the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/iamdevlinph/409807abc775172f059ca71f18b9ac4e) and the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/iamdevlinph/1gLxbb6s/30/)

The original code snippet no longer worked for Chrome and I forgot where I found it. It had safari before but I no longer have access to safari so I cannot verify anymore.

Only the Firefox and IE codes were part of the original snippet.

The checking for Opera, Edge, and Chrome is straight forward. They have differences in the userAgent. `OPR` only exists in Opera. `Edge` only exists in Edge. So to check for Chrome these string shouldn't be there.

As for the Firefox and IE, I cannot explain what they do.

I'll be adding this functionality to a [package i'm writing](https://github.com/iamdevlinph/common-utils-pkg/issues/98)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found, and does give either true or false in most browsers is:

```
var isChrome = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1 && navigator.vendor.indexOf("Google Inc") != -1)
```

Using `.indexOf` instead of `.includes` makes it more browser-compatible.
Even though (or because) the whole point is to make your code browser-specific, you need the condition to work in most (or all) browsers.

Comment: The same solution as [an existing answer from several years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53671556/215552). As noted on that answer, returns true for Edge Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

now u can use navigator.userAgent.includes("Chrome")

Answer (score -1):

Check this: [How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser/9851769)

In your case:

```
var isChrome = (window.chrome.webstore || window.chrome.runtime) && !!window.chrome;
```

Comment: Does not work on Chrome for Android neither in the browser or as PWA. Inspecting dev console shows that window.chrome is `{loadTimes: ƒ, csi: ƒ}`

Answer (score -2):

```
var is_chrome = browseris.chrome
```

or check ather browsers:

```
browseris.firefox
browseris.ie
browseris.safari
```

and olso you can check the version like `browseris.chrome7up` and etc.

check all existing information in the 'browseris' object

Answer (score -4):

all answers are wrong. "Opera" and "Chrome" are same in all cases.

(edited part)

here is the right answer

```
if (window.chrome && window.chrome.webstore) {
    // this is Chrome
}
```

Comment: Better comment than an answer.

Comment: In case you're wondering why you were modded down, this is simply not true. For one example, they handle keyboard shortcuts and access key modifiers differently (and these also cannot be feature detected).

Comment: I don't say that 'opera' and 'chrome' is the same browser only icon is different. I say that the methods described above are giving the same result for both browsers.

Comment: @Zilk Have you tested for example the first answer which has 66 up vote?

Comment: Your edited "right answer" is not correct; it will throw a ReferenceError in Firefox and others. Use either `typeof chrome` or `window.chrome`.

Comment: you're right its possible to use just window.chrome.

Comment: This will no longer work as of chrome 71. `window.chrome.webstore` is now `undefined`