# Javascript: How to find out that users browser is chrome and what is its version?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, google-chrome

How to find out if users browser is chrome and what is its version?

Comment: Just wondering, what are you looking to check for as far as a the browser's capabilities? Feature detection might serve you better for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html). This information is available in the [navigator.userAgent](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browsern.htm) property.

Answer (score 1):

Pal, its [almost related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4565112/17447).

Done a small research on detecting browsers.
[`Is this`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) what you **really** want?