# input type calendar for internet explorer and firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, input, calendar

I use often on my website intranet the input of type calendar but it works only when I use Chrome google and no using others browser. So I wrote a code for havin a css/javascript calendar but I would like to display it only if the browser is not chrome.

The calendar appear by id, so Is there a way I can check the browser ?

I really don't know which could can I use, because I don't know which functions can check the broiwser.

Receive all my utmost Respect.

Kind regards

SP.

Comment: Using JQuery to check browser - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/. Is there a reason you are not using libraries for date/calendar picker? jquery date picker - http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this to check the browser:

```
var nav = navigator.userAgent;
var ischrome = nav.indexOf("Chrome") ? true : false;

if (!ischrome) {
    // Do something for browsers other than Chrome 
    //    like displaying your calendar
    // ...
}
```

Also, an interesting link that may interest you: [JavaScript: How to find out if the user browser is Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565112/javascript-how-to-find-out-if-user-browser-is-chrome)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but will it work for all Version of this navigator?

Comment: Normally yes. I think this link might also interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565112/javascript-how-to-find-out-if-user-browser-is-chrome