# detecting non-Chrome browser and display a message

Tags: javascript, html, browser

i'm building a quick prototype and i did optimize it only for Chrome.
I'd like to detect all the browser, but chrome, so i can display an alert message about performance etc..

what's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
```

Then you can have an alert

```
if(!is_chrome){
    //display an alert
}
```

Source: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565112/javascript-how-to-find-out-if-the-user-browser-is-chrome)

Comment: Please do not copy / Paste other's answer

Comment: If your answer is a copy of somebody elses, please flag as duplicate.