# my web page is running in chrome or not?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, browser

How can i check whether the webpage is running in `Chrome` or not?
if not alert the user that you are not running in chrome:

the scenario will be like this:

```
IF webPage is not running in Firefox then
msgbox("You are not running in chrom")
End if
```

Can any one help me to do like this? am using `Asp.Net` with VB

Comment: You will have to use javascript to do that, raising message box on server makes no sense. Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13348618/351383

Comment: Do you want to detect this in `webform` or `windowsform`? If `webform`, then `msgbox` , is not the write way to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to check the value of `HttpRequest.UserAgent` - the contents of this can vary wildly across browsers ([here's a few examples](http://whatsmyuseragent.com/commonuseragents)), but in general a Chrome user agent will contain a part like `Chrome/37.0.2062.124`

So in your .aspx page, you could have something like this:

```
<% If Not HttpRequest.UserAgent.Contains("Chrome/") Then %>
  <script type="text/javascript">alert("You are not using the Chrome browser");</script>
<% End If %>
```

(I put the `<% %>` in because this doesn't go in the .aspx.vb backend page)