# How can I have a different behaviour in this jQuery script if the browser is Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

I am absolutely new in JavaScript and jQuery and I have the following problem.

I have to modify a jQuery script so that it has a different behaviour when the browser is Chrome.

This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("thead.opening").click(function () {
    alert("INTO second function");
    $(this).next().css('width', '10000000 em');
    alert(modified);
    $(this).next().css('width', '10000000 em');
    $(this).next().css('display', 'table-row-group');
    alert($(this).next().css('display'));
  });
});
```

As you can see this script perform this statement that sets the **display: table-row-group** CSS settings:

I want that if the browser is **Chrome** the script set:

```
$(this).next().css('display', 'block');
```

Can I do it in some way?

Comment: use modernizer http://modernizr.com/ detecting user agents is very unreliable

Comment: Since you are absolutely new to this stuff, I can but warmly recommend you `console.log()` instead of `alert()` :) Also, cache DOM requests in variables, e.g. `var $elem = $(this).next()`, so you can reuse `$elem` many times without querying the DOM again and again. Performance boost. You can also write `$elem.css({'width':'1000em' , 'display':'table-row'})` in one command. Finally, `$(function(){` is a shorthand to `$(document).ready(function () {.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
$(this).next().css('display', is_chrome ? 'block' : 'table-row-group');
```

**[Find chrome browser : original post from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4565120/1719752)**