# Simple Javascript code doesn't work in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Here parts from JS and HTML: *count()* works everywhere but *hideKid()* and *showKid()* only in Firefox. Chrome's debugger doesn't even achieve lines with *Kid() functions.

```js
function showKid(value) {
  document.getElementsByName('child')[value].hidden = false;
}

function hideKid(value) {
  document.getElementsByName('child')[value].hidden = true;
}
```

```html
<select name='age' onchange='count()'>
  <option onclick='hideKid(0)'>Adult</option>
  <option onclick='showKid(0)'>Kid</option>
</select>

<div name='child' hidden='hidden'>
  <select onchange='count()'>
    <option name='littleChild'>2 - 6</option>
    <option>7 - 13</option>
  </select> years
</div>
```

I also tried to put "hidden" and empty line instead of boolean type in hidden attribute. Nothing changed

Comment: don't set `click` events on `option` elements -> detect `click` event on `select` and check selected options value

Comment: the `hidden` property is pretty new, and might not be supported everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does seem to be a duplicate of the [option tag not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972280/onclick-on-option-tag-not-working-on-ie-and-chrome) @PaulRoub, but a simple work around to keep your code looking the same is to add something to the `onchange`.

```
function getSelectedOption(select) {
    return select.options[select.selectedIndex];
}
```

```html
<select name='age' onchange='getSelectedOption(this).click(); count()'>
  <option onclick='hideKid(0)' >Adult</option>
  <option onclick='showKid(0)' >Kid</option>
</select>

<div name='child' hidden='hidden'>
  <select onchange='count()'>
    <option name='littleChild'>2 - 6</option>
    <option>7 - 13</option>
  </select> years
</div>

<script>
function count() { }
  
function showKid(value) {
  document.getElementsByName('child')[value].hidden = false;
}

function hideKid(value) {
  document.getElementsByName('child')[value].hidden = true;
}

function getSelectedOption(select) {
   return select.options[select.selectedIndex];
}
</script>
```

---

This will cause another problem where FireFox fires again... So, you can check the browser and handle the clicking then. This then becomes the same answer I gave [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32865693/click-event-is-not-working-on-html-select-option-tag-in-chrome-browser/33576737#33576737). Not perfect, but gives the right result without completely reworking your current code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Clean answer

Comment: No problem! If you want, I can place part of the solution from the other question if that helps.

Comment: No, thanks, it's enough

Answer (score 0):

It is probably better to check the value of the select to hide things. The onclick on option is not suppose to bind to the options. You can bind another onchange function on the select and check the value of the select to determine which should hide. Just add the following code, should work. Here is a small demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2xb47g78/4/.

```
    var ageSelect = document.getElementsByName('age')[0];
    ageSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {    
        if (ageSelect.value == "Adult"){
            hideKid(0);
        }else{
            showKid(0)
        }         
    })
```