# Detect Chrome on mobile only

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I know how to detect chrome on iOS using `navigator.userAgent.match('CriOS')` but what i need to be able to do is to target chrome on any mobile device, and i'm having trouble doing this reliably.

Any ideas on how to do this consistently are really gratefully accepted!

Comment: are you looking for [detect chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565112/javascript-how-to-find-out-if-the-user-browser-is-chrome)?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking for `webkit` at an object property

```
if ("WebkitTouchCallout" in document.body.style) {
  // do stuff
}
```

See [List of Webkit CSS Properties for Mobiles](http://codetheory.in/list-of-webkit-css-properties-for-mobiles/)

Comment: Is that a mobile only property?

Comment: _"Is that a mobile only property?"_ No.

Comment: Then how is that detecting chrome on mobile only?

Comment: @John See updated post. Could substitute `WebKitOverflowScrolling` or `WebkitTouchCallout` for `WebkitAnimation` if requirement is only mobile properties

Comment: @John Tried `WebkitOverflowScrolling` , `WebkitTapHighlightColor` ?

Comment: Yes but they are not exclusive to mobile.

Comment: @John _"Yes but they are not exclusive to mobile"_ ? `WebkitOverflowScrolling` and `WebkitTapHighlightColor` do not appear as properties of `style` , here, at non-mobile chrome

Comment: @John Not certain which of these properties is mobile-only, though should be able to filter through, or try them, and use `for..in` to check using same approach at Answer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Webkit_Extensions , https://gist.github.com/afabbro/3759334

Answer (score -1):

```
 if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1) {
   alert('Chrome');
 }
```

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/ngn4L2hx/

**UPDATE:**

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1) {
  alert("Chrome");
}
```

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/oe4yh480/1/

Comment: That doesn't cover chrome on iOS though?

Comment: @John Try it with the `.toLowerCase()`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @RayJoe - this doesn't distinguish between Chrome on mobile and Chrome on desktop - the question seems to specifically mention Chrome on mobile.