# how to make my application url to run only on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am making my application to run only on chrome by using below code,

```
if($.browser.chrome){
 /* code if it is chrome */
}
else{
   alert("please use google chrome browser");
}
```

But I am not able to do it with this code.
Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this

Comment: A good answer using just JavaScript is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565112/javascript-how-to-find-out-if-the-user-browser-is-chrome

Comment: `But I am not able to do it with this code` why not? try throwing an error if you want to prevent the rest of the code running

Comment: try window.chrome instead of $.browser.chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here [JavaScript: How to find out if the user browser is Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565112/javascript-how-to-find-out-if-the-user-browser-is-chrome) is working for me:

```js
function isChrome(){
 var result = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
 return result;
}
           

if( isChrome() ){
 alert("App running...");
}
else{
   alert("please use google chrome browser");
}
```

Comment: Why write a function for this? Why not just place `/Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor)` into the if condition?

Comment: Because you can use the same function `isChrome()` as many time as you need.

Comment: I am glad it worked. Thanks, @AlaEddineJEBALI. Since I am checking once when starting the application I am going to use in the if only as NewToJS suggested.

Comment: @Onera well since this is just a copy/paste of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565112/javascript-how-to-find-out-if-the-user-browser-is-chrome#answer-4565120 I suggest you at least up vote the original answer or leave a comment thanking them as you found it useful.

Comment: Yes I did, Good thought @NewToJS. appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

```
if($.browser.webkit)
{

}
else
{
alert("please use google chrome browser");
}
```

Comment: not if you have jQuery -an alert wont stop code from running after you click OK