# background-size by percentage when box-sizing is border-box

Tags: css, background-size, border-box

i am trying to create a grid in a div using background.
naturally, the background-size property is a nice way to create a grid, where a size of 10% will create 10 evenly-spaced cells in the div, e.g.:

```css
div{
 width:200px;
 border:solid 1px black;
 background-size: 10% 1px;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to left, gray 1px,  transparent 1px);
}
```

```html
<div>x</div>
```

however, i also need box-sizing to be "border-box" because otherwise the box takes up more pixels than specified via the width property. and this causes all kinds of havoc in Chrome with the background-size by percentage specification, e.g.:

```css
div{background-color:white;}
#d1 { 
    width:200px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    background-size: 10% 1px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, gray 1px, transparent 1px);
    padding:5px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
#d2 { 
    width:200px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    background-size: 10% 1px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, gray 1px, transparent 1px);
    padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="d1">more than 10 cells</div>
<p>
<div id="d2">box is bigger than 200px</div>
```

note that there are more than 10 cells displayed in the top div (d1), despite the fact that each is supposed to be 10% of the div width.

it seems that this is only a Chrome issue, but if someone has the solution to this, please let me know.

Comment: By `grid`, you mean *background pattern*, right?

Comment: The `background-size` `CSS` property specifies the size of the background images. The size of the image can be **fully constrained** or only **partially** in order to preserve its **intrinsic ratio**. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: yes, i am trying to create a custom progressbar where the bg pattern creates an evenly divided grid. i'd then be able to use js to change the grid density. but i definitely want to use percentage to specify cell width in the grid because progressbar width might change, as well.

Comment: Found out ***how***. No idea ***why*** :)...

Comment: Firefox renders both correctly, looks like a Chromium bug to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrei Gheorghiu's answer was really good, but wasn't consistent across all browsers, and was a few pixels off for some separator locations. Anyway, here's the more consistent answer, seems to work everywhere:

```css
div { 
  background-color:white;
  width:200px;
  border:solid 1px black;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to left, red, red 1px, white 2px, white 10%);
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

div ~ div { 
  width:300px;
  }
```

```html
<div>exactly 10 red separators</div>
<div>also exactly 10 red separators</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I admit I never played with this thing before, but it looks like you need to account for the `1px` width of the `background-image`. Now don't ask me why, but it just works. Tested it with different percentages and widths. If you need the ***why***, not only the ***how***, you'll have to dig through W3C's docs yourself or wait for a better documented answer.

```css
div { 
  background-color:white;
  width:200px;
  border:solid 1px black;
  background-size: calc(10% + 1px), 1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, gray 1px, transparent 1px);
  padding:5px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

div ~ div { 
  width:300px;
  }
```

```html
<div>exactly 10%</div>
<p>
<div>also exactly 10%</div>
```

Cheers!

Comment: First time I tried with `10% -  1px`, cause that made sense to me. But at `200px` it created 11 boxes. Changing `%` and `width` I realized I need `+ 1px`. Weird indeed.

Comment: tho this won't work correctly in firefox or ie; is there a way to make this a chrome-specific solution but leave the 10% for other browsers?

Comment: Not sure, they rarely needed. I'll search and find a way :).

Comment: it's ok, that can be done via JS:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565112/javascript-how-to-find-out-if-the-user-browser-is-chrome

Answer (score 0):

Check the progress bar code. How it work?

```css
.progress-bar{
background-color: blue;
background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
background-size: 40px 40px;
height: 40px;
width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar"></div>
```

`background-size: 40px 40px;` that means `40px` width and `40px` width for the box. **How two `width` work tougher?** `background-size` First place **image** then place **gap**. Background image will start `0 to 40px` then place `40px` gap then `40px` image. It's infinity until full `width` is complete. Look your first snippet `background-size: 10% 1px;` Browser render **10 gap** from total `width` using `1px` **width image**.

> **Note:** `background-size` will work when you set `background-image`. Otherwise `background-size` property will not work.

Hope this help.