# Alert when page opened not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, if-statement, alert

I'm trying to get an alert to pop up when the user opens my webpage in a browser other than Chrome. I have this:

if (/*what to put here to make the below show only if the browser is not Google Chrome?*/) {
    alert( "Please use Google Chrome to access this site.\nSome key features do not work in browsers other than Chrome." );
}

Found this here as a possible condition: navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome"), but can't make it work. Please advise. :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: How to find out if the user browser is Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565112/javascript-how-to-find-out-if-the-user-browser-is-chrome)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565112/javascript-how-to-find-out-if-the-user-browser-is-chrome might answer your question

Comment: Popups are not the best solution. If possible - better to check if these features are working in the current environment and if not to show let say a div with a warning instead. There may be browsers you don't know where those features are working.

Comment: Better test on features instead of browser type

Answer (score 3):

As the comments above point out by referencing questions you can test for chrome in the userAgent. But you would want to reverse that:

```js
    let notChrome = !/Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent)
    
    let alertMessage = "Please use Google Chrome to access this site.\nSome key features do not work in browsers other than Chrome."
    if(notChrome) alert(alertMessage)
```

This will solve the problem unless the user is spoofing their userAgent. This is unusual though. To fully check you should also check for a feature chrome has AND the userAgent:

```js
        let notChrome = !/Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !("webkitAppearance" in document.body.style)
        
        let alertMessage = "Please use Google Chrome to access this site.\nSome key features do not work in browsers other than Chrome."
        if(notChrome) alert(alertMessage)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should to it.

```js
var isChrome = !!window.chrome; // "!!" converts the object to a boolean value
console.log(isChrome); // Just to visualize what's happening

/** Example: User uses Firefox, therefore isChrome is false; alert get's triggered */
if (isChrome !== true) { 
  alert("Please use Google Chrome to access this site.\nSome key features do not work in browsers other than Chrome.");
}
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work for some reason. What works is:  if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1 ){;}
 else {
 alert("Please use Google Chrome...");}  //out of FF, IE and Edge only Edge doesn't display the alert, thou that's not a big deal, as all seems to work there fine.

Comment: @RavMucha Hm, that's strange. I tested it in Chrome and FF. FF triggered the alert, Chrome did not. For me it worked. But I'm glad you found another solution.