# detect chrome browser, and execute a custom function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, window, navigator

I am trying to implement a function to detect chrome browser and then execute a particular function on the fly.
We have a webpage where document links are displayed and on click on it, the document is downloaded.

the requirement is to enable the kiosk machines which uses chrome browser to open a document in a new tab as the download and opening the document is restricted in Kiosk machines.

to determine whether the browser is chrome, i have used below approaches.

1. using userAgent -- below approach returns true for other browsers as well

   `this.isChromeBrowser = (/(?!.*chrome).*/i).test(navigator.userAgent);`
2. using window.chrome, below code was working when i implemented, but now it is giving issues and it returns false for chrome browser.  (window.chrome.webstore & runtime are undefined).

`this.isChromeBrowser = !!window.chrome && (!!window.chrome.webstore || !!window.chrome.runtime);`

3. i am thinking of using implementation 1 along with window.navigator.vendor

`this.isChromeBrowser = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);`

or

`this.isChromeBrowser = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor) && window.chrome;`

Need some inputs on which would be a better solution to use. 
i am more inclined towards implementation 3, as we would be checking the useragent as well as the vendor.

============ 
update :
the implementation and extensive explanation is already provided in the below link. this give my answer.

[JavaScript: How to find out if the user browser is Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565112/javascript-how-to-find-out-if-the-user-browser-is-chrome/13348618#13348618)

Comment: did you read all in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565112/javascript-how-to-find-out-if-the-user-browser-is-chrome/13348618#13348618

Comment: @canbax thanks foe the pointers, the link answers all my questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: How to find out if the user browser is Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565112/javascript-how-to-find-out-if-the-user-browser-is-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

I have used this in the past:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") > 0){
   //yourfunction
}
```

Answer (score 0):

update the links which already answers the question which i posted,