# What if user with eel python doesn't have chrome installed

Tags: python, electron, eel

I want to create an offline app with web UI. I came to know about eel which is much simple than the Electron where I had to bring this node.js into the play.

But once I create a exe file with PyInstaller the issue for me is that, some users who install the app won't have chrome and eel will open it in edge. But my UI looks worse in edge.

So my question is how can I embed chromium in my exe. so that if the user doesn't have chrome installed it opens up in chrome itself like how electron does the job by having its own chromium included.

Any method is acceptable as I dont care for the size of the exe.
Also is there someway that I can make the eel window non resizable, ie always have a fixed width and height only without the option of user to drag and resize or maximise the window ?

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly harder given that the .exe the program is and not a install wizard.
The easiest and cleanest way is a chrome check in you application [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565112/javascript-how-to-find-out-if-the-user-browser-is-chrome).
You will let the user know to install it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after googling for a while i got this: https://github.com/ChrisKnott/Eel/issues/287
Basically you get a portable web browser and put its executable on your app folder then create a mode for it. then you use this new mode i.e :

```
eel.start('index.html', mode='my_portable_chromium', 
                        host='localhost', 
                        port=27000, 
                        block=True )
```